# PHP equivalent to filter js

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, object, filter

I'd like to translate this code in PHP:

```
let example = [
{id:'1', name:'abc', type:'123'},
{id:'2', name:'def', type:'345'},
{id:'3', name:'ghi', type:'678'},
{id:'4', name:'lmn', type:'901'}];

let res = example.filter(x => x.type != '901' && Number(x.id)>=2);
```

But I don't know the equivalent function of JS's filter; i found array_filter but only for simple array, not array of objects

Comment: Looks like [array_filter()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

you can filter $array like this:

```
function not_901($var)
{
    return $var != 901;
}

print_r(array_filter($array, "not_901"))
```

---

Edit:

If you want the translation of your code in PHP here it is:

```
<?php


$example = [
    ['id'=>'1', 'name'=>'abc', 'type'=>123],
    ['id'=>'2', 'name'=>'def', 'type'=>345],
    ['id'=>'3', 'name'=>'ghi', 'type'=>678],
    ['id'=>'4', 'name'=>'lmn', 'type'=>901]
];


function not_901($var)
{
    return $var['type'] != 901;
}


print_r(array_filter($example, "not_901"));
```

Comment: Unless the filter function should be reused in other places, it's cleaner to use an anonymous function: `array_filter($array, function ($item) {  ... });`